# Can't seem to load CSS in a custom theme

Tags: 8, theming

[image]

I'm working on trying to add CSS to a custom theme, and it seems my logic is failing somewhere.

I'm adding simple css files in the .libraries.yml on the root of the theme (only thing in them right now is forcing a background color on the body) and not one of the css files is loading.

Where does my logic fail here?

This is in Drupal 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have a call to your library in your .info.yml

```
libraries:
 - pixelcircus/global
```